# custom google form email notification

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the below app script to generate a random id in the header UID in the google form response sheet and then by default the script is mailing the UID to the form user who is submitting the form.

I want the script to generate the random uid but instead of sending the UID value in the email it should let me specify another header where I am tweaking the random UID.

any help will be highly appreciated.

```
const sheetName = "Responses"; // replace this sheet name with yours
    const uidHeader = "_UID"; // column name of UID in response sheet
    const uidPrefix = "UID-"; // UID prefeix
    const uidDigitLength = 5; // digit length of UID
    
    function _onFormSubmit(e) {
      const { rowStart } = e.range
      var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getFormUrl();
      var form = FormApp.openByUrl(url);
      var response = form.getResponses().pop();
      var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
      const editUrl = response.getEditResponseUrl()
      var responseId = response.getId();
      // for sequential id
      //var uid = createUid(responseId);
      
      // for random id
      var uid = createRandomUid(responseId);
      writeUidToSheet(uid, rowStart);
      
      var title = "Thanks for your submission";
    //  var lastItem = response.getItemResponses().pop();
      var email = response.getRespondentEmail();
      if (email){
        var subject = form.getTitle();
        var htmlBody = "<table style='width: 600px; margin: 10px auto; background: #dfe4ea;'><tr>" +
                       "<td style='padding: 0px 20px;'>" +
                        "<h2 style='text-align: center; letter-spacing: 0.1em; background: linear-gradient(60deg, #16a085, #1abc9c); color: #fff; padding: 10px;'>" +
                         title + "</h2>" +
                         "<p>UID</p>" +
                         "<div style='padding: 20px;border-radius: 20px; background: linear-gradient(60deg, #16a085, #1abc9c);'>" +
                           "<div style='font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; color: #ecf0f1; text-align: center;'>UID</div>" +
                           "<div style='font-size: 25px; color: #2c3e50; text-align: center;'>" + uid +"</div>" +
                         "</div>" +
                         "<p><a href='"+ url +"' style='color: #16a085;'>Submit another response</a></p>" +
                         "<p><a href='"+ editUrl +"' style='color: #16a085;'>Edit your response</a></p>" +
                         "<p>Thanks,<br>Ashton Fei</p>" +
                         "</td></tr></table>";
        var options = {
          htmlBody: htmlBody
        };
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", options);
      }
    }
      // Write uid to the responses sheet
    function writeUidToSheet(uid, rowStart){
      var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      var dataRange = ws.getDataRange();
      var values = dataRange.getValues();
      var headers = values[0];
      var indexUid;
      
      // Locate the index of header UID
      for(var c = 0; c < headers.length; c ++){
        if(headers[c] === uidHeader){
          indexUid = c;
          break;
        }
      }
      
      // Insert a new column in B if UID column is not found
      if (indexUid === undefined){
        ws.insertColumnsAfter(1, 1);
        indexUid = 1;
        ws.getRange("B1").setValue(uidHeader);
        dataRange = ws.getDataRange();
        values = dataRange.getValues();
      }
      
      // Check UID's in the sheet row by row
      var isNewUid = true;
      for (var r = 1; r < values.length; r ++){
        var currentUid = values[r][indexUid];
        if (currentUid === uid){
          isNewUid = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      
      if (isNewUid){
        ws.getRange(rowStart, indexUid + 1).setValue(uid)
      }
    }
      
    
    // Create a UID in document properties
    function createUid(responseId){
      var docProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
      var key = "uid";
      var id = 1;
      if (docProperties.getProperty(responseId)){
        var uid = docProperties.getProperty(responseId);
      }else{
        if(docProperties.getProperty(key)){
          id = parseInt(docProperties.getProperty(key));
        }
        
        var uid = (Math.pow(10, uidDigitLength) + id).toString().substring(1, uidDigitLength+1);
        uid = uidPrefix + uid;
        
        docProperties.setProperty(key, id + 1);
        docProperties.setProperty(responseId, uid);
      }
      return uid;
    }
    
    // function a random uid in document properties
    function createRandomUid(responseId){
      var docProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
      var key = "randomUids";
      var ids = [];
      if (docProperties.getProperty(responseId)){
        var uid = docProperties.getProperty(responseId);
      }else{
        if(docProperties.getProperty(key)){
          ids = JSON.parse(docProperties.getProperty(key));
        }
        
        do{
          var randomNumber = Math.pow(10, uidDigitLength) + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, uidDigitLength));
          var uid = randomNumber.toString().substring(1, uidDigitLength + 1);
          uid = uidPrefix + uid;
        }while (ids.indexOf(uid) !== -1)
        
        ids.push(uid)
        docProperties.setProperty(key, JSON.stringify(ids));
        docProperties.setProperty(responseId, uid);
      }
      return uid;
    }
    
    // Remove all properties from the document properties object, so the uid can be reset
    function resetForm(){
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var prompt = "This action will delete all responses in the form";
      if (ui.alert("Confirmation",prompt, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL) === ui.Button.OK){
        PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().deleteAllProperties();
        const url = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getFormUrl();
        const form = FormApp.openByUrl(url)
        form.deleteAllResponses();
        var msg = 'All responses have been deleted and UID has been reset. You need to manually remove the old data in sheet "' + sheetName + '".';
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(msg, "Google Apps Script", 15);
      }
    }
    
    
    
    function onOpen(){
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu("Scripts")
        .addItem("Reset form", "resetForm")
        .addToUi();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `it should let me specify another header where I am tweaking the random UID`, can you clarify this? Also, can you explain what you tried, and what specific problems you faced? Are you getting any error?

Comment: by default it is sending the UID to the user who is submitting the form, in another column I am concatenating the uid and generating a new no which I want to share with the users on notification mail.

Comment: I'm sorry but still don't understand what you want to accomplish. It seems like your script is sending a custom `UID` by email and also adding that `UID` to a certain column in the sheet. Therefore, what is missing here, what's your purpose now?